# Laravel 8.1 IdGenerator

Tags: php, laravel-8

im a Laravel newbie and i try do generate Customerid for my Customer.Create.
My idea is to use they [IdGenerator](https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-custom-id-generator) to generate id and then set the Id automatic in disabled input field on my creat.blade.php.

But im not shure is this idea right.
i write this in my web.php:

```
use Haruncpi\LaravelIdGenerator\IdGenerator;
    Route::get('/customer/create', function(){
    $config = ['table' => 'customers', 'length' => 10, 'prefix' => 'K-'];
    $id = IdGenerator::generate($config);
    return $id;
    });
```

and this is the html snippen from my create.blade.php

```
<div class="col-auto">
                              <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Firma</label>
                              <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                      <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-building"></i></div>
                                  </div>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="{{ $id }}" disabled>
                              </div>
                          </div>
```

but i get everytime this erros message:

> Exception table field type is bigint but prefix is string

Can you help me, is this the right way or do you have a better idea?

greetz Marcel

Answer (score 0):

Change the field type of `prefix` to char and in your `/database/migrations/your_table.php`
change `$table->bigInt('prefix')` to `$table->char('prefix')` and then rerun your migrations **Make sure you do not delete important data from your database please check the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations) if you are not sure what you're doing.**